# How to get all documents from couchdb using lightcouch api in java

Tags: java, couchdb

Is there any way to get all documents from a db rather than specifying an id and retrieving a single document **using lightcouch api** in Java.Presently i am using the method

JsonObject json = dbClient.find(JsonObject.class, "some-id")
to retrieve a single document.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about the [`_all_docs`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#all_docs) view?  That will return a list of all the docs in the database.  Or if you include `include_docs=true` to the request, you will also get the contents of the documents.

Comment: Showing the following error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid View URI. Expecting a format: design_doc_name/view_name at org.lightcouch.View.<init>(View.java:112) at org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.view(CouchDbClient.java:151) at retriveCouchData.main(retriveCouchData.java:37)

Comment: need to create view in all db and provide the path dbClient.view(" design_doc_name/view_name ")

Comment: I've never used LightCouch before so that was a guess.  Looking more at the API it looks like it is not possible to get to the built in view easily.  You can write the same _all_docs view and put it in your design doc easily, but I dont know if that will have the same performance.

Comment: Fyi, querying the special view `_all_docs` is now supported within the existing Views API. So @DustyCampbell suggested solution would work, eg: `List<JsonObject> allDocs = dbClient.view("_all_docs").includeDocs(true).query(JsonObject.class);` However, it's not yet published in a release at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... use a view that emits documents, but don't send any key values. There is a chance you will get all the documents of the type you specified. Also, a warning... if you use a LightCouch view, you might need to retrieve the id's of your documents, then get your actual data by "finding" it using those id's.